# Hide attribute type dropdown if no value

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, attribute-set, dropdown-attribute, category-attribute

I use this code to hide attributes when they do not have data:

```
        <?php foreach ($_additional['items'] as $_data): ?>
         <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This works great, but not for the type dropdown attributes.
**How can I also hide dropdown attributes, that do have any value?**

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple function if you are using product collection to display product's attribute

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {

 echo  $product->getAttributeText('color');
}
```

hope this will work for you

Comment: Thanks, but that does only effect the color attribute.
I need to effect all dropdown attributes